# How to find the head file that contains MAJOR defination in linux?

Tags: linux, gcc

When I compile a c code file in linux , there occured some questions below:

1. undefined reference to 'MINOR'
2. undefined reference to 'MAJOR'

I guess some head files are not included or some head files have changed as time goes on.But I am not sure which head file changed or no inluded.I use grep command to find some head file that includes MAJOR macro defination but no help.
linux version:

- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 15.10
- Release: 15.10
- Codename:    wily

The .c file includes head files below:

```
 <stdio.h>  /* fprintf */
 <string.h>
 <stdlib.h> /* contains exit */
 <sys/types.h>  /* unistd.h needs this */
 <sys/stat.h>
 <linux/fs.h>
 <unistd.h> /* contains read/write */
 <fcntl.h>
```

I have searched google but find nothing.Any suggestion is helpful .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the dev_t type defined in linux/types.h

and macros found in linux/kdev_t.h

you can reference
[Major and Minor Numbers](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-2)

Comment: Thank you so much.